# PHP: I want to count the occurrences of specific number of words from a text file

Tags: php

```
<?php
$count_array = array("if","world");
$file = fopen('Data.txt', "r");
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = fgets($file);
    if(trim($line) == "")
    continue;
    $OBJ = json_decode($line);
    foreach($count_array as $word)
    {
      echo '<b>' . $word . ' occurance are ' . substr_count(strtolower($OBJ->user->text), $word) . " times.</b><br />";
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is the code. It just keep looping until the file ends, because foreach is inside the while loop and if I put outside it only checks the first line it gets.

Output:

```
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 1 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
if occurance are 0 times.
world occurance are 0 times.
```

...(so on)

I want like this:

```
if occurance are 47 times.
world occurance are 7 times.
```

Comment: Would `file_get_content()` be a better option to read the whole file in one go?

Comment: If you put the entire wordlist into an array, you could just use `array_count_values($count_array)` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php for more info)

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `json_decode` on a  text file :-/

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what `Data.txt` contains?

Comment: its a twitter dump file

Comment: I'm not sure what "a twitter dump file" is or how it's formatted. Please provide a sample of what its contents are. i.e. the approach will be different if it's just a CSV-formatted file vs JSON vs line-delimited dictionary.txt file, etc.

Comment: {"created_at":"Fri Oct 06 09:57:20 +0000 2017","id":916240952460759040,"id_str":"916240952460759040","text":"https:\/\/t.co\/FHTVWAGhgx","display_text_range":[0,0],"source":"\u003ca ,"truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":818144785672372224,"id_str":"818144785672372224","name":"-","screen_name":"vz_9999","location":null,"url":null,"description":".","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":117,"friends_count":5

Comment: So depending on what `user->text` is here (assuming it's the text of a tweet?) you're going to need something like `str_word_count($OBJ->user->text);` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to parse the text and figure out the different words in `$OBJ->user->text`. I'll update my answer below to account for that.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks sir. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$count_array = ["if" => 0,"world" => 0];

$file = fopen('Data.txt', "r");

while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($file));

    $words = explode(" ", $line);

    foreach($words as $word) {
        if (array_key_exists($word, $count_array)) {
            $count_array[$word]++;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($count_array as $word => $number) {
    echo $word . " occurred " . $number . " times" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Example Data.txt

```
asd lol rotflol if
world rotflol world
bubu hehe gnigni if if
if hehe if world
```

Result:

```
$ php script.php
if occurred 5 times
world occurred 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the entire wordlist into an array, you could just use

```
$counts = array_count_values($count_array)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php for more info (or http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php to read in a line). Then `$counts` would be something like

```
Array
(
    [if] => 47
    [world] => 7
    [otherword] => 17
)
```

Then you could loop through that list to check if the word is in your wordlist and echo appropriately like

```
foreach($counts as $word => $number) {
    if (in_array($word, $count_array) {
        echo $word.'</b> occurrence is '.$number.' times.<br>';
    }
}
```

or better yet

```
foreach($count_array as $word) {
    echo $word.'</b> occurrence is '.intval($counts[$word]).' times.<br>';
}
```

And to parse the line and count the number of words you'll want to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php instead of `explode(' ', $line);` because `explode(' ', 'word word.');` would return `array(0 => 'word', 1 => 'word.')` (note the period is included because you just exploded on spaces) vs `str_word_count('word word.', 1)` would return `array(0 => 'word', 1 => 'word')` (easier to loop through and count).

Edit, adding full (untested) code:

```
$count_array = array("if", "world"); //words to search for and count

$word_counts = array();
//initialize the array like [word] => 0
foreach($count_array as $w) {
    $word_counts[$w] = 0;
}

$file = fopen('Data.txt', "r");
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($file));
    if ($line != "") {
        $OBJ = json_decode($line);
        $words = str_word_count($OBJ->user->text, 1); //return associative array of words

        foreach($words as $w) { //go through the list of returned words
            if (in_array($w, $count_array)) { //if this word is in our $count_array
                $word_counts[$w]++; //count it!
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($word_counts as $word => $count) {
    echo '<b>' . $word . ' occurance are ' . $count . " times.</b><br />";
}
```